# How to access/set 'select' tag in HTML with python

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, mechanize

I'm trying to extract events from a page of HTML - http://www.staffordshire-pcc.gov.uk/space/

I want to select different areas using python but came unstuck with the following HTML:

```
<select data-ng-options="key as value.name for (key,value) in areaGroups | orderBy:'name'" data-ng-model="selectedAreaGroup" data-ng-change="updateAreaGroup()" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
    <option value="" class="" selected="selected">Choose an area</option>
    <option value="string:CannockChase" label="Cannock Chase District">Cannock Chase District</option>
    <option value="string:EastStaffordshire" label="East Staffordshire">East Staffordshire</option>
    <option value="string:Lichfield" label="Lichfield District">Lichfield District</option>
    <option value="string:Newcastle" label="Newcastle Borough">Newcastle Borough</option>
    <option value="string:SouthStaffordshire" label="South Staffordshire">South Staffordshire</option>
    <option value="string:Stafford" label="Stafford Borough">Stafford Borough</option>
    <option value="string:StaffordshireMoorlands" label="Staffordshire Moorlands">Staffordshire Moorlands</option>
    <option value="string:SoTCentral" label="Stoke-on-Trent Central">Stoke-on-Trent Central</option>
    <option value="string:SoTNorth" label="Stoke-on-Trent North">Stoke-on-Trent North</option>
    <option value="string:SoTSouth" label="Stoke-on-Trent South">Stoke-on-Trent South</option>
    <option value="string:Tamworth" label="Tamworth Borough">Tamworth Borough</option>
```

I use Mechanize to find forms on pages, but as there's no form attached to the  tag, I can't work out how I would select it, and then submit a value.

What's the best option for me to pursue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the form by the order at which it appears on the page, firstly import & open

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open('http://www.staffordshire-pcc.gov.uk/space/')
```

Loop through all the forms in the page

```
forms = [f.name for f in br.forms()]
```

Lets check whether form[0] is the correct index for the form with the dropdown (as in your question) Set the control variable and print out the values

```
control = forms[0].controls[0]
form_values = [item.attrs['value'] for item in control.items]
print form_values
```

If this it the correct form you should see:

```
["string:CannockChase", "string:EastSta....
```

If not cycle through the indexes until you find the correct index (* see below).

Finally once you have found the correct form you can set a value and submit:

```
br.form[0*] = form_values[0]
r = br.submit()
// read out the HTML from the resulting page
print r.read()
```

* this index is whichever represents the dropdown form as in your question

Comment: I was half way there, but couldn't work out the item.attrs['value'] bit. Thank you for your time.